# Get battery level of connected smartwatches

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to get the battery level of connected smartwatches as part of the Wear API? (Preferably without having to deploy an actual wear-component onto the smartwatch and then communicating back-and-forth between the watch and the device). I've seen some wear-apps that show the battery level of the watch on the watch itself, but I'd simply like to find out the current battery level of the watch *using the phone*.

Comment: I guess you need to go via the data api and a micro app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're more than likely going to need a wear app, but it should be very easy.

On the wearable, make a `WearableListenerService`. Have the phone app send a message (using the [Message APi](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)). This will start the `WearableListenerService` on the watch. Have the watch get it's battery information and send it back to the phone using another message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up going down this road and it works well. Not what I had hoped for (because it puts some strain on the wearable, even if it's just minimal), but it works :-)!

Answer (score -2):

Start by determining the current charge status. The BatteryManager broadcasts all battery and charging details in a sticky Intent that includes the charging status.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

You can extract the current charging status this way

```
// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
```

you can use this one

```
public static final String EXTRA_LEVEL
```

> ```
> Added in API level 5
> Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer field containing the current battery level, from 0 to      EXTRA_SCALE.
>
> Constant Value: "level"
> ```
>
> You can find the current battery charge by extracting the current
>   battery level and scale from the battery status intent as shown here:

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale; // your %
```

**so batteryPct is your Battery % Percentage**

> //you can show your Percentage then

For more info about BatteryManager from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html)

Comment: Hi Nadir, thanks for the detailed answer. Please note that the question was how to get the battery status of smartwatches connected to the phone, not the battery level of the phone. Your answer only gets the battery level of the phone.