# Get battery level of the phone from smartwatches

Tags: android, wear-os

I try to find a way to get the phone's battery level from a watch wearable device.

I found this answer but it is the opposite (get wear battery level from the phone) : [Get battery level of connected smartwatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884383/get-battery-level-of-connected-smartwatches)

If I send a message from wearable to the phone (using companion activity), will I be able to send back the info ? What if companion activity not started (example: android wear stopped) ?
Is there simple way to get that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same way:

1. Wear:Connect the GoogleApiClient
2. Wear:Send message to mobile handheld
3. Mobile: Define a WearableListenerService which receives the message 2
4. Mobile: send a message to the wear device
5. Wear: Implement a MessageApi.MessageListener interface which receives the  message 4
6. Wear: Receive the message and use a LocalBroadcastManager to elaborate the message and display the value on the wear